# Is there any option to listen to a voice call on a bluetooth device and on the phone speaker at the same time ?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to be able to make phone calls with the phone while the bluetooth device is recording the phone calls so I want to know if there is an option to duplicate the voice stream of the phone call to another device (bluetooth) while the regular phone speaker and microphone are working.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#startBluetoothSco%28%29) and implement the following codes.

```
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
int state = intent.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, -1);
Log.d(TAG, "Audio SCO state: " + state);

if (AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED == state) { 
    /* 
     * Now the connection has been established to the bluetooth device. 
     * Record audio or whatever (on another thread).With AudioRecord you can record with an object created like this:
     * new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
     * AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, audioBufferSize);
     * After finishing, don't forget to unregister this receiver and
     * to stop the bluetooth connection with am.stopBluetoothSco();
     */
    unregisterReceiver(this);
}

}
}, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED));

Log.d(TAG, "starting bluetooth");
am.startBluetoothSco();
```

The orignal discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455797/recording-audio-from-a-bluetooth-audio-device-in-android).